# Ajax GET but php variable is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

i try to send via ajax a simple string, but the php GET var is null. Thank you

```
function postJSON(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://www.my-server.de/file.php",
data: { 'dataString': "juhu" },
cache: false,
success: function()
    {
        alert("Order Submitted");
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

php:

```
 <?php 
 echo "Value is:";
 echo $_GET['dataString']; ?>
```

Comment: see your console for any error..

Comment: What result are you getting and what result do you expect?

Comment: Where do you see null? you haven't got the chance to see any result

Comment: Which "php POST var" ? You are using GET here

Comment: I´m sorry, i mean the "php GET var". The console have no error and the result should be "Value is: juhu"

Comment: Your not going to see any result unless to get the result

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You should try this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://www.my-server.de/file.php",
   data: { 'dataString': "juhu" },
   cache: false,
   success: function( response ){
       alert( response );
   },
   error: function() {
       alert("Error");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks,
now i get the php output in a alert box on my android phone, but this output should be **on the webpage**;)

Comment: Well, that is not your question, your question was why your not getting the result, and that's solved. try here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-dom-webdesign , you need to gain 20 rep, though